# Host sudirectory with Nancy

Tags: c#, web, nancy

Hello I am trying to host a simple HTML site with Nancy selfhosting.

I also need some js files that a stored in a subdirectory “scripts”.

Here is my Bootstrapperfunction for the subdirectory:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(Nancy.Conventions.NancyConventions nancyConventions)
{
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("scripts", "scripts"));
    base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
}
```

Now if I install Nancy in version 1.0.0. and start the program and open the browser, I cannot load any js files.

For all js files I get an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

With Nancy in version `0.23.2` it works perfectly with the same code, the same html and the same js files.

Is this a bug or is there a different configuration in version `1.0.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into this known issue: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1789

Comment: Thanks, var config = new HostConfiguration { AllowChunkedEncoding = false }; solve the problem.